# Magento2.3.1 i want to remove wishlist link from top.links but not working

Tags: magento2, layout, wishlist, toplinks

I have added  below code in my custom Magento_Theme default.xml file to remove top.links

```
  <referenceBlock name="top.links">
     <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
      <!--for Create Account Link-->
      <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
      <!--for WishList Link-->
      <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
      <!--for My Account Link-->
  </referenceBlock>
```

all other links removed but wishlist not remove

Comment: Do you talk about comes in the dropdown?

Comment: yes,which are included in top.links block  @RaviSoni

Comment: Your added code is working in fresh setup. wish-list-link

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the link using your store admin panel. In order to do this, log into your Magento store admin panel.

> Admin > Store > Configuration > Customer > Wishlist >General option > Enable

Set to **No** Click on the Save Config button.

[image]

> Run php bin/magento c:f

Take reference from here [Magento 2. How to Manage Top (Header) Links](https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-1-x-manage-top-header-links/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: why it's working?  what is Admin > Store > Configuration > Customer > Wishlist >General option > Enable?

Comment: See this link https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-1-x-manage-top-header-links/

Comment: It removes wishlist link from header top link.

Comment: if have not set above config to No then it's working using <referenceBlock name="multiple-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
anyway thanks!!

Comment: Welcome. thanks for appreciation :) +1 for appreciation

Comment: But still one query.. it will disbale whole wishlist funtionality or just disabke top links?

Comment: Ok, let me check.

Comment: I think you are right it will remove the whole functionality.
But as per your above comment, i see `<referenceBlock name="multiple-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>` will work.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150436/removing-wishlist-link-top-header-magento-2

Comment: Make sure if you are using enterprise edition then `<referenceBlock name="multiple-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>` it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Remove Wishlist Link From Header in magento2.3.1,You can only add this line in your `defualt.xml`.

```
<referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/vendorName/themeName/Magento_Wishlist/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call

```
<referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
```

under

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
```

Just put it under

```
<body>
```

and

```
</body>
```

tags, without covering it under its parent block.

The final block should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        ...
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

Note: Although your file path seems correct, for any other person having a similar problem, the file path should be like **app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_Wishlist/layout/default.xml**